# My problem: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time;

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
func updateArrowPosition() {
    let width = text!.size(withAttributes: [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: defaultFont as Any
    ]).width
    let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: (frame.size.width - width) / 2 + width + downArrow.width / 2, y: height / 2 - downArrow.height / 2)
    downArrow.origin = newOrigin
    LibManager.shared().location.sublocations.count > 1 ? (downArrow!.isHidden = false) : (downArrow!.isHidden = true)
  }

extension UIView {
 func height() -> CGFloat {
  return frame.size.height
  }
}
```

[image]

My error:

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

i read that, if Swift encounters something with so many possibilities that it simply can’t figure it out after about 15 seconds, it throws an error instead: “Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.”

I understand that I need to "break" my code into 2 parts so that this error "goes away". 
I don’t understand how to break the code

Comment: `LibManager.shared().location.sublocations.count > 1 ? (downArrow!.isHidden = false) : (downArrow!.isHidden = true)` oh boy, that's a mess. You could just simplify that to `downArrow?.isHidden = !LibManager.shared().location.sublocations.empty`

Comment: Calculate `frame.size.width - width`. Calculate that `/ 2`. Calculate `width + downArrow.width`. Calculate that `/ 2`. Do I have to keep going? Finally, put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the problem at hand is a compiler error due to the time it takes to type-check this expression, that's really the least of your worries.

Code like this:

```
let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: (frame.size.width - width) / 2 + width + downArrow.width / 2, y: height / 2 - downArrow.height / 2)
```

Might make sense to you now, and perhaps tomorrow, and maybe in a few weeks. But it doesn't make any sense to other people, including 1-year-in-the-future-you. Why is there this subtraction? Why is it being divided by 2? Then some addition?

You should break this expression down into named sub-expressions that express the intent of what you're trying to do. I can't really do that for you, because I have absolutely no idea what these calculations are trying to achieve.

Here's a start:

```
func updateArrowPosition() {
    let width = text!.size(withAttributes: [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: defaultFont as Any
    ]).width

    let newOriginX = (frame.size.width - width) / 2 + width + downArrow.width / 2 // What the fuck?
    let newOriginY = height / 2 - downArrow.height / 2
    downArrow.origin = CGPoint(x: newOriginX, y: newOriginY)

    downArrow?.isHidden = 1 < LibManager.shared().location.sublocations.count
}
```

I would suggest you further break down `newOrigin(X/Y)`, and explain what all those arithmetic terms are doing.

Further:

1. Don't use the conditional operator for such long expressions. It's hard to read. Just use an `if`/`else`. In this case, you could simplify even further, you don't need a branch at all.
2. I wouldn't recommend writing that extension `UIView.height()`.

   1. That should be a computed property, not an parameterless function.
   2. There's no reason to use `frame.size.height`, when `CGRect` already has a direct `height: CGFloat` member. Just use `frame.height`
   3. It's not clear if that's the height of the `frame` or the `bound`. By the time you rename it to `frameHeight`, you may as well have just used `frame.height`.